# Projecting a table in COSMOS and using it with "Not In" clause

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Hi I want to write a COSMOS DB Query to retrieve all the ID's that are not in the given list (this is static list I want to project as a table).  To make it easy to understand, I'm giving SQL Server Version of the query

```
select t.id from 
(
select 1 as id Union All
select 2 as id Union All
select 3 as id Union All
select 4 as id 
) t 
where t.id not in 
(
     select c.Id from SomeTable c
 )
```

Similar to the above, I want to project data as t in COSMOS DB query and I want to check against the existing "c" in COSMOS DB to find what are all the missing ID's.  Struggling to find a good example query.

Projected table (t) will have the data as
[
{"id" : "1"},
{"id" : "2"},
{"id" : "3"},
{"id" : "4"}
]

Cosmos Db table (c) will have this data
[
{"id" : "1"},
{"id" : "2"}
]

I want the result to show what are the items/records missing in C that is present in t

Expected output

[
{ "id" : "3",
"id" : "4"
}
]

Remember t is static data (projected and not in COSMOS), c is the table/data that is available in COSMOS

Comment: can you provide sample document and output you need?

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan, Just assume the both the document structure are simple just one attribute

{ "id" : "idvalue1"}

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're asking, as you provided a SQL Server query (plus, what does "what are all the missing IDs" mean?). I suggest editing your question  (as suggested in the first comment) to show sample data, along with what outcome you're tying to achieve. There's really nothing here to "just assume"...

Comment: @DavidMakogon, edited my question to add example input/output

Answer (score 1):

By reading the initial statement in your question, it seems that you want to filter ids of records/documents which are not present in a static list.
However, the SQL Server query example posted will give us ids from static list which are not there in Cosmos DB collection i.e. `NOT IN` clause in your query. Cosmos DB does not support cross collection queries, creating temporary tables, variables or `UNION`/`UNION ALL` statements.

If you want to achieve what you have mentioned in the initial statement "*I want to write a COSMOS DB Query to retrieve all the ID's that are not in the given list*". You can do so by passing static list values in the query and using the `NOT IN` clause.
Sample query as below.

```
SELECT c.id FROM c WHERE c.id NOT IN ('1', '5', '6')
```

I have created three records for sample data with id values 1,2,3. After running the above query I am getting the result as 2,3 which excludes the record with id 1, which is part of the static list i.e. ('1', '5', '6').

Comment: Thanks @RitikaNalwaya for sharing your thoughts and the sample query, I want the reverse I want to see what is missing in C from the given list.  If c.id is missing 1 or 5 or 6 I want to get that.